# how to properly erase a line incrementally? (i.e., animated)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a javascript that draws a line in an animated way like this:

```
function drawLeftLine() {
  var yoffset = 500;
  var startX = 0;
  var startY = yoffset;
  var endX = canvas.width;
  var endY = yoffset;
  var amount = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
      amount += 0.03; // change to alter duration
      if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
      //c.clearRect(1, 1, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      c.beginPath();
      c.strokeStyle = "black";
      c.moveTo(startX, startY);
      // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
      c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
      c.stroke();
      c.closePath();
  }, 30);
}
```

I want to erase that line in an animated way (i.e., it should look like its being erase).  I tried doing this by drawing a white line over top of it using that same code but changing the stroke color to white.  The result is a "grey" looking line.  Even if I draw a significantly wider white line over it, it still can sometimes show through.  You need to view it in full screen:

http://jsfiddle.net/3D9jt/5/embedded/result/

Here is the full code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3D9jt/5/

What is a good way to erase this line incrementally?  Keep in mind there are other things on my canvas.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: check that your paint isn't 'transparent' when drawing over the line.